# Is Item service search API allow to filter by more than one template?

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I am using `Sitecore 10.2` and want to use `Item service API` to get items by template so in the facet I want to add more than one value in the template filter however I am unable to figure out the correct syntax to achieve that I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
"/sitecore/api/ssc/item/search?includeStandardTemplateFields=False&fields=ItemName%2CTemplateName&term=sitecore&facet=_templatename%7Cevent, banner
```

but when it filters by only one template it retrieves the results correctly.

Anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Item Service search API is very limited.

It does not allow to use multiple templates in search query.

I checked if there is an option to create your own implementation of `IItemSearch` class, which is used to execute the search, but as far as I can say, it's hardcoded to use `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Data.ItemSearch` class so nothing can be done in order to support multiple templates.